# Array indexoutofboundsException:3

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

Can't figure out why my `int[][] totalOpenness = new int[n][n];`array continously goes out of bounds exception:3. My calculations of my `public static void openfactor(char[][] mazeValue, int n)` method are working fine; however, I get an array index out of bounds error on the following 2 lines inside my `openfactor(char[][] mazeValue, int n)` I can never seem to make it through my whole array, not even close. PLEASE HELP! :)

```
totalOpenness[i][j] = openness;
System.out.println("TOTAL OPENESS FOR : [" + i + "]" +"[" + j + "]  IS " +totalOpenness[i][j]);
```

```html
import java.util.*;
public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("ENTER A SINGLE INTEGER: ");
    int n = kbd.nextInt();
    char[][] mazeValue = new char[n + 1][n + 1];
    System.out.println("ENTER A PATH: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < mazeValue.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mazeValue[i].length; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == n + 1 || j == n + 1)
                mazeValue[i][j] = 'X';
            else {
                mazeValue[i][j] = kbd.next().charAt(0);
            }
        }
    }
    printMaze(mazeValue);
    openfactor(mazeValue, n);
}
public static void printMaze(char mazeValue[][]) {
    System.out.println("MAZE");
    for (int i = 1; i < mazeValue.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < mazeValue[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%5c", mazeValue[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }
}
public static void openfactor(char[][] mazeValue, int n){

       int[][] totalOpenness = new int[n][n];
       for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
       {  
           
           for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
          {

              int count=0;
              int openness=0;

               if(mazeValue[i][j]=='X'){
                   System.out.println("tHIS IS AN X FOR : [" + i + "]" +"[" + j + "] IS -1 ");
                   count--;
               }

              else 
               {
               //YOU NEED TO VERIFY THAT J IS NOT OUT OF BOUND
               if( j-1>=1)
                    {
               if(mazeValue[i][j-1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                      // System.out.println("cout: "+count);

                    if(i-1>=1 && j-1>=1)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i-1][j-1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                     //  System.out.println("cout: "+count);
                     if(i-1>=1)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i-1][j]=='O')
                        count++;
                     }
                    //   System.out.println("cout: "+count);
                    if(j+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i][j+1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                     //  System.out.println("cout: "+count);
                    if(j+1<=n && i+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i+1][j+1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (i+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i+1][j]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                    //   System.out.println("cout: "+count);
                    if(j-1>=1 && i+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i+1][j-1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
                    if(i-1>=1 && j+1<=n)
                    {
                    if(mazeValue[i-1][j+1]=='O')
                        count++;
                    }
            //}//eND OF iF CONDITION\
            }
            openness = openness +count;
            totalOpenness[i][j] = openness;
            System.out.println("TOTAL OPENESS FOR : [" + i + "]" +"[" + j + "]  IS " +totalOpenness[i][j]);
           
         }
      }
   
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [the documentation for `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than **or equal to the size of the array**.

You are using 1-based indexing with java arrays, which use 0-based indexing ([Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)):

```
for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
  for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
```

will give an exception at `i=n` as `totalOpenness[n][anynumber]` is an invalid array index, this is because it is declared with `int[][] totalOpenness = new int[n][n]` so the element indexes are `0, 1, ..., n-1`.

Change your loops to be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
```

Unfortunately the logic inside the `for` loop also seems to assume 1-based indexing, so you will have to change that as well.

Comment: I use 1 because I have a boarder of X values surrounding my current array. If I start at 0 it will just store part of my boarder wont it?

Comment: Yea it just stores my boarder.

Comment: Then you need to declare it as `int[][] totalOpenness = new int[n+1][n+1]`, in which case the indexes will be `0, 1, ..., n`. Either way java array indexes are 0-based so the maximum index is one less than the length.

Comment: I did that, and it does work, It is staying in bounds, but doing that causes it store my Invisible boarder. This is how I had it, It still keeps storing the invisible boarder.